# Updating a property with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

I'm developing an iOS 4 application using latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I have enabled ARC on my project, and I'm trying to migrate a previous project to a new one that uses this feature (ARC).

The problem comes from an setter implementation. Here is my class (old version):

```
@interface RouteView : MKAnnotationView
{
    /**
     */
    MKMapView* _mapView;

    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView* mapView;
```

And its implementation:

```
@implementation RouteView

@synthesize mapView = _mapView;

-(void) setMapView:(MKMapView*) mapView
{
    [_mapView release];
    _mapView = [mapView retain];

    [self regionChanged];
}
```

I get two compiler errors in the two first line on `setMapView:` method.

How can I do a custom setter method with ARC enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ARC, you no longer need to release/retain objects, as it has automatic reference counting that puts retain and release calls in at compile time.

As a quick fix when merging an old program, you can comment out any lines that have:

- `[myObject retain]`
- `[myObject release]`

Just make sure that you don't remove any functionality when you remove that part. In your application, you would need to replace `[mapView retain]` with `mapView`, as you still need to set the object, just without retaining it.

So your `setMapView` method would look something like this:

```
-(void) setMapView:(MKMapView*) mapView
{
    //[_mapView release];          //Don't need this line anymore.
    //_mapView = [mapView retain]; //Don't need this line either.

    _mapView = mapView //You still want to set the mapView, just not retain it.

    [self regionChanged];
}
```

Comment: "it has automatic garbage collection" This is untrue. It has automatic reference counting, which is totally different from garbage collection. ARC inserts retain and release at compile-time into your code for you. Garbage collection happens at runtime and watches your object graph for entities that are no longer in use. It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this with ARC:

```
-(void) setMapView:(MKMapView*) mapView
{
    _mapView = mapView; // direct assignment to a strong ivar; let ARC do its thing

    [self regionChanged];
}
```